# Frozen closure with useCallback/useMemo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been seeing odd behavior in which `useCallback` function doesn't seem to be able to access outer scope.

This is described here: [How does React Hooks useCallback "freezes" the closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577294/how-does-react-hooks-usecallback-freezes-the-closure)

Although it can be easily re-calculated by adding all things to the array, it does seem counter-intuitive. So I'm wondering what's the best way to handle it.

Here's the code

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import useEventListener from '../../hooks/use-event-listener';
import tinybounce from 'tinybounce';
import Scroll from '../../utils/scroll';

export default function DefaultMainPlayer({ children, className }) {
    const [scrollThreshold, setScrollThreshold] = useState(0);
    const [inView, setInView] = useState(true);
    const [didUserClose, setDidUserClose] = useState(false);
    const el = useRef();
    const scrollHandler = useCallback(() => {
        // scrollThreshold and inView get "frozen" unless they're on the array below
        const isVisible = Scroll.getPosition() <= scrollThreshold;

        if (inView !== isVisible) {
            if (inView) {
                setInView(isVisible);
                setDidUserClose(false);
            }
        }
    }, [scrollThreshold, inView]);
    const cx = classNames('main-player', className, {
        'is-fixed': !inView && !didUserClose
    });
    const resizeHandler = useCallback(
        tinybounce(() => setScrollThreshold(Scroll.getElementCoordinates(el.current).bottom), 300),
        []
    );

    // If scroll threshold updates, lets call the scroll handler
    useEffect(scrollHandler, [scrollThreshold]);
    // Call the resize handler once
    useEffect(resizeHandler, []);

    // I'd like the scroll handler to never change since it really doesn't need to
    useEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    useEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);

    return (
        <div className={cx} ref={el}>{children}</div>
    );
}
```

Here's the code for `use-event-listener``

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useEventListener(eventName, handler, element = window) {
    const savedHandler = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        savedHandler.current = handler;
    }, [handler]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const isSupported = element && element.addEventListener;
        if (!isSupported) return;

        const eventListener = event => savedHandler.current(event);

        // Add event listener
        element.addEventListener(eventName, eventListener);

        // Remove event listener on cleanup
        return () => {
            element.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListener);
        };
    },
    [eventName, element]
    );
};
```

I'm trying to avoid `scrollHandler` to be changing all the time because functions aren't equal. I've tried `useMemo` (returning the function as a value) but the result is the same. Don't get `scrollThreshold` updated.

Although these two variables could seem "a little" it could easily need more and it just feels wrong.

Is there any way to fix this or approach it differently?

Comment: How is `useEventListener` handling the received function?

Comment: I've added the code @Alvaro

Comment: Thanks Antonio. As far as I understand the only issue is with `scrollHandler` not using the correct `scrollThreshold`? And there doesn't seem to be any problem with `useEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);`, right?

Comment: Yeah, `useEventlistener` does work correctly, calls on scroll and the one below for `resize` does work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are using a state variable inside the callback which is then set inside `useEffect`. There is probably no simple way to handle this, see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14066#issuecomment-435458108).

Two options

---

Do not use `useCallback`. This way when running the function it will use the latest `scrollThreshold` and `inView`. Also pass the changing variables to `useEventListener`, or any hook that uses it, as dependencies of the `useEffect` (this would need some refactor):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const isSupported = element && element.addEventListener;
    if (!isSupported) return;

    const eventListener = handler;

    // Add event listener
    element.addEventListener(eventName, eventListener);

    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => {
        element.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListener);
    };
}, [eventName, element, scrollThreshold, inView]);
```

---

Use `useCallback` with `scrollThreshold, inView` as dependencies.
In `useEventListener`, or any hook that uses it, use the function passed as a dependency in the adding/removing event handler:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const isSupported = element && element.addEventListener;
    if (!isSupported) return;

    const eventListener = handler;

    // Add event listener
    element.addEventListener(eventName, eventListener);

    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => {
        element.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListener);
    };
}, [eventName, element, handler]);
```

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Seems like Classes are less cumbersome for this sort of components then! (for now) thanks!