# React context not keeping data in state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am trying to use React context to replace my actual Redux.
I want to use this context to store an array of files.
This is a nextjs app, I do not know it can cause some issues

I have my `FileContextProvider`

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const FileContext = createContext({});

export function FileContextProvider({ children }) {

    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('files', files);
    }, [files])

    const addLocalFiles = (newFiles, mode) => {
        console.log('addLocalFiles', files);
        setFiles([...files].concat(newFiles));
    }

    return (
        <FileContext.Provider value={{
            files,
            addLocalFiles
        }} >
            {children}
        </FileContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Then I created a global context where I want to initialize all my context, at the moment I only have the file one.

```
import { FileContextProvider } from "./file";

export default function Context({ children }) {

    return (
        <FileContextProvider>
            {children}
        </FileContextProvider>
    );

}
```

Then I add the context in `_app.js`

```
import Context from '../context';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <Context>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Context>
  )
}

export default MyApp;
```

In one of my child component I have

```
import { FileContext } from '../../context/file';

export default function TopBlock({ type, format }) {

    return (
               <div className="col-12 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                   <FileContext.Consumer>
                       {({ files, addLocalFiles, removeFile, updateFile }) => (
                                    <UploadBlock files={files} addLocalFiles={addLocalFiles} />
                       )}
                   </FileContext.Consumer>
               </div>
    );

}
```

Here my `UploadBlock`

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';

export default function UploadBlock({ files, addLocalFiles }) {

    const dropzoneParent = useRef(null);

    function MyDropzone() {
        const onDrop = useCallback(async acceptedFiles => {
            addLocalFiles(acceptedFiles)
        }, [])

        const dropOptions = { onDrop }
        const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone(dropOptions)

        return (
            <div {...getRootProps()} ref={dropzoneParent}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <div>Drop Here</div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
            <div>
                {MyDropzone()}
            </div>
    )

}
```

In my `UploadBlock` when I call `addLocalFiles` it's working, I have my `files` variable containing my new files but if I call a second time `addLocalFiles` the previous files does not exist in `FileContextProvider` , `console.log('addLocalFiles', files);` is returning an empty array.

The `useEffect` is only to debug, it is triggered each time `addLocalFiles` is called, and new files are well print.

I do not understand why `files` from the state became an empty array when I am calling back `addLocalFiles`

I have only one instance of `Context` and `FileContext.Consumer` I do not know if it makes any changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, `states` are dependent on specific render. It means, every render will have its own `states`. So, by the time `addLocalFiles` are declared, specific `files` states are dependent on the render.

```
const addLocalFiles = (newFiles, mode) => {
  console.log('addLocalFiles', files);
  setFiles([...files].concat(newFiles)); // state `files` are used
}
```

I think the problem could be that you are wrapping `addLocalFiles` function with `useCallback`.

```
const onDrop = useCallback(async acceptedFiles => {
  addLocalFiles(acceptedFiles)
}, []) // empty dependency, so it will always referencing same `addLocalFiles` function.
```

`addLocalFiles` will never be generated again, even if it renders. So, changed states `files` are not going to be applied in `addLocalFiles`.
If you want to prevent useless re-render, you should specifying its dependency, `files`.

```
const onDrop = useCallback(async acceptedFiles => {             
  addLocalFiles(acceptedFiles, mode)
}, [addLocalFiles]); // this function is dependent on `files`
```

Or you can just skip `useCallback`, if optimization is not really necessary. I found a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577294/how-does-react-hooks-usecallback-freezes-the-closure) question that could help you better understading.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, you helped me to resolve my issue
`const onDrop = useCallback(async acceptedFiles => {
            addLocalFiles(acceptedFiles, mode)
        }, [addLocalFiles])`

This worked

Comment: Good to hear that, edited my answer.

Comment: @Ajouve and did the answer code I posted at first doesn't work at your codes?

Answer (score 0):

please provide your  component so we can be sure how u call the `addLocalFiles` method with the required parameter.
i also think there is no need for spreading [...files].concat(newfile) instead of files.concat(newfile)